# grails list view odd/even class name for row

Tags: grails, model-view-controller

Grails seems to auto add either 'even' or 'odd' to the class name of a row element in the list table.

```
<g:each in="${instanceList}" status="i" var="instance">
     <!-- test with no clas names assigned-->
     <tr id="${instance.id}">

 renders
   <tr class='odd' id="1">
```

Is this true for all grails projects? I inherited one using 2.2.+
I'd rather like to stop that from happening. Anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on the scaffolding templates that get included with Grails. You can use the `install-templates` command ([see docs](http://docs.grails.org/2.4.x/ref/Command%20Line/install-templates.html)) and then edit the corresponding template to change/remove this.